# Where can I find the full documentation of deployment descriptor(web.xml)

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-3.0, deployment-descriptor

Is there a full documentaion of the deployment descriptor that describes each element and each sub-element?
I realy can't find it.

P.S. I ask because I found the way to set maxAge of session cookies by adding

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>525600</session-timeout> 
    <cookie-config>
        <max-age>31536000</max-age>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

into DD. But I cannot find any official documentation that describes `<cookie-config>` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the standard Java EE deployment descriptor elements, that follows the servlet 3.0 specification, you can address, for instance, Oracle's Weblogic 12c [web.xml docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/web_xml.htm#WBAPP502).

Furthermore, for the missing sub-elements that aren't contemplated in the documentation mentioned above, I'd suggest you to give a look to the [web-common_3_0.xsd](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-common_3_0.xsd) file, which *is the common XML Schema for the Servlet 3.0 deployment descriptor (...) in turn used by web.xml and web-fragment.xml web application's war file.*

Event though it will force you to read XML, in this file you may check all the elements, as well as their sub-elements, that can be used in *web.xml* deployment descriptor as, for instance, the `cookie-config`:

```
<xsd:element name="cookie-config"
             type="javaee:cookie-configType"
             minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>

        The cookie-config element defines the configuration of the
        session tracking cookies created by this web application.

        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that XML Schema contains English description of elements.